# Go code running result in local environment is not same with run in go play

Tags: go

I am using `Go` to implement an algorithm described below:

> There is an array,only one number appear one time,all the other numbers appear three times,find the number only appear one time

My code listed below:

```
import (
    "testing"
)

func findBySum(arr []int) int {

    result := 0
    sum := [32]int{}

    for i := 0; i < 32; i++ {
        for _, v := range arr {
            sum[i] += (v >> uint(i)) & 0x1
        }
        sum[i] %= 3
        sum[i] <<= uint(i)
        result |= sum[i]
    }

    return result
}

func TestThree(t *testing.T) {
    // except one nubmer,all other number appear three times
    a1 := []int{11, 222, 444, 444, 222, 11, 11, 17, -123, 222, -123, 444, -123}  // unqiue number is 17
    a2 := []int{11, 222, 444, 444, 222, 11, 11, -17, -123, 222, -123, 444, -123} // unque number is -17
    t.Log(findBySum(a1))
    t.Log(findBySum(a2))
}
```

However,I found that the running result in my PC is wrong,and the same code running in **https://play.golang.org/p/hEseLZVL617** is correct,I do not know why.

Result in my PC:
[image: The result in my PC is wrong]

Result in **https://play.golang.org/p/hEseLZVL617**:
[image]

As we see,when the unique number is positive,both result are right,but when the unique number is negative,the result in my PC in wrong and the result online is right.

I think it has something to do with the bit operations in my code,but I can't find the root cause.

I used IDEA 2019.1.1 and my Golang version listed below:
[image]

I don't know why the same code can works fine online and do not work in my local PC,can anyone help me analysis this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size of `int` is platform dependent, it may be 32-bit and it may be 64-bit. On the Go Playground it's 32-bit, on your local machine it's 64-bit.

If we change your example to use `int64` explicitly instead of `int`, the result is the same on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YOnXwnm4uHo) too:

```
func findBySum(arr []int64) int64 {

    result := int64(0)
    sum := [32]int64{}

    for i := int64(0); i < 32; i++ {
        for _, v := range arr {
            sum[i] += (v >> uint64(i)) & 0x1
        }
        sum[i] %= 3
        sum[i] <<= uint(i)
        result |= sum[i]
    }

    return result
}

func TestThree(t *testing.T) {
    // except one nubmer,all other number appear three times
    a1 := []int64{11, 222, 444, 444, 222, 11, 11, 17, -123, 222, -123, 444, -123}  // unqiue number is 17
    a2 := []int64{11, 222, 444, 444, 222, 11, 11, -17, -123, 222, -123, 444, -123} // unque number is -17
    t.Log(findBySum(a1))
    t.Log(findBySum(a2))
}
```

You perform bitwise operations that assume 32-bit integer size. To get correct results locally (where your architecture and thus size of `int` and `uint` is `64-bit`), change all `int`s to `int32` and `uint` to `uint32`:

```
func findBySum(arr []int32) int32 {

    result := int32(0)
    sum := [32]int32{}

    for i := int32(0); i < 32; i++ {
        for _, v := range arr {
            sum[i] += (v >> uint32(i)) & 0x1
        }
        sum[i] %= 3
        sum[i] <<= uint(i)
        result |= sum[i]
    }

    return result
}

func TestThree(t *testing.T) {
    // except one nubmer,all other number appear three times
    a1 := []int32{11, 222, 444, 444, 222, 11, 11, 17, -123, 222, -123, 444, -123}  // unqiue number is 17
    a2 := []int32{11, 222, 444, 444, 222, 11, 11, -17, -123, 222, -123, 444, -123} // unque number is -17
    t.Log(findBySum(a1))
    t.Log(findBySum(a2))
}
```

Lesson: if you perform calculations whose result depend on the representation size, always be explicit, and use fixed-size numbers like `int32`, `int64`, `uint32`, `uint64`.

Comment: @lucumt Run the 2nd code. The first code is to prove the Go playground can also provide the wrong result.

Comment: Thank you very much,now I got the result I expected,is the reason that by default my environment is 64bit,so all the int is 64bit,and thus can not get the right answer?

Comment: @lucumt Yes. You perform bitwise operations that assume 32-bit integer size.

Comment: I want to known is there a way to write platform independent code for my code,I tested it in `Java`,`Python` and `Go`,only in `Go` meet this problem

Comment: Yes, if you use `int32`, it will be platform independent. It's the `int` type that may vary from platform to platform (and also `uint`). If you want portable code, don't use `int` and `uint` if the number you intend to store in them might require more than 32 bits.